# Grails - Referencing Absolute URL in gsp

Tags: list, url, grails, hyperlink, tags

In my index.gsp for one of the column values for a table I provide the following:

```
<td><g:link action = "redirect(url: 'http://www.google.com')">www.google.com</g:link></td>
```

However, the link that shows on the page is ->

```
http://localhost:8080/APP_NAME/VIEW_NAME/redirect(url: 'http://www.google.com')
```

What's the workaround to avoid the inclusion of the base url in the beginning. I want the link to be the absolute URL ->

```
http://www.google.com
```

---

Based on some of the comments below, the following works ->

```
<td><a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a></td>
```

However, when I reference the field of a bean that I wish to display like this ->

```
<td><a href=${fieldValue(bean: testRunInstance, field: "artifactLink")}>${fieldValue(bean: testRunInstance, field: "artifactLink")}</a></td>
```

the link displays correct (www.google.com), while the actual link resolves to ->

```
http://localhost:8080/APP_NAME/www.google.com
```

How do I eliminate the reference to the below Base URL?

```
http://localhost:8080/APP_NAME/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the tag anchor of the standard HTML

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>
```

**EDIT**

You can change:

```
<td><a href=${fieldValue(bean: testRunInstance, field: "artifactLink")}>${fieldValue(bean: testRunInstance, field: "artifactLink")}</a></td>
```

By:

```
<td>
    <a href="http://${testRunInstance.artifactLink}">
        ${fieldValue(bean: testRunInstance, field: "artifactLink")}
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: @chandragaajula You are welcome. In order to follow StackOverflow rules, I suggest you remove your answer.

Comment: Deleted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

or this, if you want `<g:link>`

```
<g:link url="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</g:link>
```

Comment: Just for curiosity: If we do it on this way. There is a performance impact (obviously so minimum) parsing gsp to html?

Comment: There is, but it's so small compared to all the other areas of your application it's not going to even show up when you profile your application and look for bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use

```
     <g:link url="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</g:link>
```

Comment: Your suggestion results in the link -> "http://localhost:8080/APP_NAME/VIEW_NAME/redirect(url: www.google.com, absolute:true)"

Comment: yep its definetly wrong with your "action" parameter. simply use an anchor or the url parameter of g:link

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example, where artifactLink has a value, ddg.gg
<g:link base="http://" uri="${bean.artifactLink}">${bean.artifactLink}</g:link>
// Generates
<a href="http://ddg.gg">ddg.gg</a>


// Example, where artifactLink has a value, http://ddg.gg
<g:link base="http://" uri="${bean.artifactLink}">${bean.artifactLink}</g:link>
// Generates
<a href="http://ddg.gg">http://ddg.gg</a>


// Example, where artifactLink has a value, https://ddg.gg
<g:link base="http://" uri="${bean.artifactLink}">${bean.artifactLink}</g:link>
// Generates
<a href="https://ddg.gg">https://ddg.gg</a>
```

It ignores the `base` attribute altogether, when encounter a protocol in front of the `uri` value. Notice, it doesn't repeat `http://` in the 2nd example, and used `https://` instead, in the last one.

Moreover, you can specify `target="_blank"`, so page loads in a new tab or window.

NB: Should work for Grails 3.2 or >.